# What is Apache process model?

Tags: apache, processmodel

I have been googling this question for some time but got no answers. What's the Apache  process model?

By process model, I mean how Apache manage process or thread to handling HTTP request.

Does it fork one process for each HTTP request?

Does it have process/thread pool?

Can we config it?

Is there any online doc for such Apache details?

Comment: Although you should address this question to serverfault.com, I'll note that Apache has few modules for different request handling (fork, thread, mpm, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

This depends on your system and configuration : see [Core Features and Multi-Processing Modules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/) : you could use, for instance :

- [Apache MPM winnt](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_winnt.html) on windows -- that one uses threads
- Or [Apache MPM prefork](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/prefork.html) -- that one uses processes
- Or even [Apache MPM worker](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html) -- which uses both several processes and threads.

Quoting the page of the last one, Apache MPM worker :

> This Multi-Processing Module (MPM)
>   implements a **hybrid multi-process
>   multi-threaded** server.  
> By using
>   threads to serve requests, it is able
>   to serve a large number of requests
>   with fewer system resources than a
>   process-based server. 
> However, it
>   retains much of the stability of a
>   process-based server by keeping
>   multiple processes available, each
>   with many threads.